# How to get workflowIsntanceId and taskId in workflow execution

Tags: netflix-conductor

Here below is a definition of two Tasks, 1st one is HTTP and 2nd is HUMAN, in HTTP task need to pass workflowInstanceId and HUMAN taskId.

I am not able to find a way to get workflow contextual data. Help is appreciated.

```
{
                "name": "fullfill_order_for_medicine",
                "taskReferenceName": "fullfill_order_for_medicine",
                "inputParameters": {
                    "http_request": {
                        "uri": "http://localhost:7777/orders",
                        "method": "PUT",
                        "body": {
                            "id": "${get_order_request.output.response.body.id}",
                            "name": "${get_order_request.output.response.body.name}",
                            "status": "complete",
                            "isComplete": true,
                            "WorkflowId":"${workflowInstanceId}",
                            "TaskId":"${dispatch_approval.taskId}"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "type": "HTTP"
            },
            {
                "name" : "dispatch_approval",
                "taskReferenceName": "dispatch_approval",
                "type": "HUMAN"
            }
```

Comment: use ${workflowInstanceId} for workflowId. https://conductor.netflix.com/devguide/labs/eventhandlers.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this `${workflow.workflowId}`